# How can I add a legend to geom_function in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot, how can I add a legend entry for each of the `geom_function`s so that the color and linetype are displayed (e.g for `fun1` a short dotted red line), along with a custom name that I choose?

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = seq(0, 1, by=0.01)), mapping = aes(x=x)) +
  geom_function(fun = fun1, linetype='11', color='red') +
  geom_function(fun = fun2, color='dark green') +
  geom_function(fun = fun3, linetype='dashed', color='blue')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define them inside `aes`, here is an example with 3 random functions

### Code

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = seq(0, 1, by=0.01)), mapping = aes(x=x)) +
  geom_function(fun = dnorm,aes(col = "fun1"))+
  geom_function(fun = dexp,aes(col = "fun2"))+
  geom_function(fun = sin,aes(col = "fun3"))+
  #Defining the colors
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","black","purple"))
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: But what if I want to use specific colors for each function?

Comment: You can set them with `scale_colour_manual`, for example, `scale_colour_manual(values= c("black","red","purple")`

Comment: I updated my answer @AnIgnorantWanderer

Comment: what about the linetype? is it not possible for it to appear in the legend?